# listview items error(style of multiple items is being changed)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

i'm trying to change color of listview item on click but when i do that it's changing color of another listitem also which is not in view. so the issue is that current commands i'm using use current viewable items in view to change color. since list has some 20 items and 5 are visible per view. if i click on 1st item then every 5th item on scroll when comes to view get's it's color changed. what i want is only that item to change color. i'm getting chilcount as 5 but position count of listview items is upto 20.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            System.out.println("ArrayList Of Values :"+ lv.getItemAtPosition(position) + position + " " + position + "-" + id);
                           /* if(view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){

                                view.setBackgroundColor(0xff39fff7);
                            }*/
                            String values= lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                            System.out.println(position + " " + id);
                            JSONArray jsonArray;
                            final ArrayList<String> listOfValues = new ArrayList<String>();
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(values);
                                String date = jsonObj.getString("date");
                                String slot1 = jsonObj.getString("slot1");
                                listOfValues.add( slot1);
                                listOfValues.add( date);
                            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());

                            }
                            if(listOfValues.get(0) == ""){
                                selectedtime.setText("not available");
                            }else{
                                Integer ki = 0;
                                String alpha = "yes";

                                if(alpha == "yes"){

                                    int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
                                    Drawable background = getViewByPosition(position,lv).getBackground();
                                    if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
                                        color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
                                    if(color == Color.parseColor("#ff39fff7")){
                                        System.out.println(lv.getChildCount()+"position is="+position);

                                     //lv.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
getViewByPosition(position,lv).setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
                                    }else{


                                        getViewByPosition(position,lv).setBackgroundColor(0xff39fff7);
                                        //lv.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(0xff39fff7);
                                    }
                                }





                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
```

adapter function

```
public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String s = "";

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_date, null);

            final ListView gridView = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_viewsub);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.email);
            holder.text.setId(94171+position);
            //final ViewParent bd = holder.icon.getParent();
           final Context acontext = new TabFragment1().getContext();
 convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
try{
            s = contactList.get(position).toString();
            JSONObject c = contactList.getJSONObject(position);


            String slots;
            String id;
            String date;
            String names;
            String slot1_value;
            slots = c.getString("slot1");
            JSONArray names_json = c.getJSONArray("names");
            holder.text.setText(slots);
}
        catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());


        }

        return convertView;



    }
```

Truong's solution - ok it worked well for single selection but i have to make multiple selections in app. and that is again causing that error

```
 int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;
        Drawable background = convertView.getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
            color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();
        if(positionChangedColor != null){
if(position == positionChangedColor) {
    // color your item here

    + Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    if(color == 0 || color == -1) {
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xff39fff7);

    }else if(color == Color.parseColor("#39fff7")){
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);

    }
}else {
    // you have to change color to normal to avoid it is recycled

    if(color == Color.parseColor("#ff39fff7")) {

    }else{
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you use view holder on your listview's adapter?

Comment: yes sir. i did used.

Comment: convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_date, null); also referenced my view properly to viewholder along with one textview that list item contains

Comment: Ok, if you are using view holder. It mean the item view will be recycled. That's why when you scroll, every 5th item your item getting color changed.

Comment: i added adapter code. ok so what's the solution for that sir?

Comment: look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The first, I suggest you should not color you item view in `onItemClick`. In stead, you update the position to the adapter. I named the variable save the position(will be changed color) as `int positionChangedColor;`

1. In your `onItemClick`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
         // your logic as normal
        // now you want to change color
        yourAdapter.updateChangedColorPostion(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```
2. In your adapter create method

   ```
   private void updateChangedColorPostion(int position) {
          positionChangedColor = position;
   }
   ```
3. And in `getView`

   ```
   public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // your code as normal

      if(position == positionChangedColor) {
         // color your item here
      }else {
         // you have to change color to normal to avoid it is recycled
      }

      return convertView;
   }
   ```

Comment: should i still use holder or not?

Comment: use holder as possible as you can, it related to performance.

Comment: should i use onclick method within adapter class?

Comment: it's up to you guys

Comment: i think i got it working i'll mark answer as correctly shortly sir. thanks

Comment: hey could you please check the new code that i updated. your solution worked fine for single color change/selection but for multiple it again caused same error

Comment: You can create boolean array instead of positionChangedColor to handle multiple selected. The length of this array is same with your array dataset and have default value is 'false'. If you select any item at specific position, you update the value at the same position in boolean array to 'true'. In getView method instead of checking position == positioinChangedColor, you only need to check value at that position in boolean array. If it return true, then color the item and vice versa.
Let me know if you need any help